# External display shows black borders on iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, screen, border, hdmi

Problem: The external screen connected through HDMI cable shows black borders on all sides. I already have tried setting the overscanCompensation property with no luck.
The problem occurs only if app is run on iOS 8, on iOS 7 external (TV) screen shows no borders.

I can't find overscan configuration on my Samsung TV though.

Any suggestions what I could try additionally?

Answer (score 0):

Until now I can't find any solution to this black border... The old tricks like set the
overscanCompensation to '3' does not work now.

Workaround with Apple TV:
If you can use an Apple TV, you are able to disable this overscaling  on your Apple TV: Settings > Audio & Video > Adjust For AirPlay Overscan. Set it to Off (default On).

I hope that Apple will create an option the user to be able to disable this on his/her iDevice...